# which algorithm uses a multidimension array of average probabilities

Tags: algorithms

**Is there an algorithm that returns the mean probability of response from a multi-dimensional matrix?**

For example, if I have a set of features:

- customerClass = `poor` / `middle` / `rich`
- category = `11` / `20` / `35`
- offerValue = `$1` / `$2` / `$3`

and a response:

- usesCoupon = FALSE / TRUE

Assuming I have enough samples, I want to predict the probability for a new sample (customerClass = `rich`, category = `20`, offerValue = `$1`) as the average probability for the population with the same three-dimensional value `(rich, 20, $1)`.

Comment: A logit regression?

Comment: @Sergio Logistic regression means to assume a linear function. A matrix of average probability would not make any assumption: it would just give the average for similar data. Or?

Comment: What do you mean by the average probability for the population with the same three-dimensional value? This algorithm would just be you taking a subsample of the already-classified data which are exactly the same as the new input and counting how many are `TRUE` and how many are `FALSE` would it not?

Comment: @Matthew Yes. If there are 200 people classified as (rich, 20, $1), and they are 30% TRUE in those 200 people, then 30% is my probability guess.

Comment: I think you've already defined the algorithm to the letter. You would just need to write the code yourself. Perhaps it already has a name and an implementation in some preexisting software package, but I don't know it.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, that is what I started doing, but if I can find a library it could be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The following function `f` will find the probability you're after. It's important that the input vector `x` is of the same length and in the same order as the rows of your data frame `df`, or else the `duplicated` function will not work as intended. You will need to customize this function to handle missing data & work with different dependent variable columns, as `usesCoupon` is assumed.

```
f = function(x, df){
    # x is a vector of inputs the same length & order
    # as the second dimension of df without usesCoupon
    features = df[, !(colnames(df) %in% c('usesCoupon'))]
    rows = duplicated(rbind(x, features))[-1]
    how.many.true = as.numeric(df[rows,]$usesCoupon == TRUE)
    return(mean(how.many.true))
}
```

I imagine there are more efficient ways to do this, but this should work fine for manageable data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the mean response of answers from the subset of your data. You can completely describe the subset by the index (customerClass, category, offerValue) and the responses (n_uses_coupon, n_total). This could be stored in a pair of dictionaries:

```
uses_coupon = dict()
all_responses = dict()
```

To 'train' your model, simply insert data into the dictionaries:

```
def fit_on_sample(customerClass, category, offerValue, response):
    if (customerClass, category, offerValue) not in all_responses:
        all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue] = 0
        uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue] = 0
    if response:
        uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue] += 1
    all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue] += 1

def fit(samples, responses)
    for (customerClass, category, offerValue), response in zip(samples, responses):
        fit_on_sample(customerClass, category, offerValue, response)
```

To make predictions with this model, simple lookup the counts and calculate the mean:

```
def predict(customerClass, category, offerValue, threshold=0.5, response_on_missing=None):
    if (customerClass, category, offerValue) in all_responses:
        used_coupon = uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue]
        total_responses = all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue]
        score = int(used_coupon) / total_responses
        return int(score >= threshold)
    else:
        return response_on_missing
```

If you wrap this in a class you can use multiple instances of it:

```
class LocalMeanPredictor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.uses_coupon = dict()
        self.all_responses = dict()

    def fit_on_sample(self, customerClass, category, offerValue, response):
        if (customerClass, category, offerValue) not in self.all_responses:
            self.all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue] = 0
            self.uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue] = 0
        if response:
            self.uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue] += 1
        self.all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue] += 1

    def fit(self, samples, responses)
        for (customerClass, category, offerValue), response in zip(samples, responses):
            self.fit_on_sample(customerClass, category, offerValue, response)

    def predict_with_sample_size(self, customerClass, category, offerValue, response_on_missing=None):
        if (customerClass, category, offerValue) in self.all_responses:
            used_coupon = self.uses_coupon[customerClass, category, offerValue]
            total_responses = self.all_responses[customerClass, category, offerValue]
            score = int(used_coupon) / total_responses
            return int(score >= threshold), total_responses
        else:
            return response_on_missing, 0

    def predict(self, customerClass, category, offerValue, response_on_missing=None):
        return predict_with_sample_size(customerClass, category, offerValue, response_on_missing)[0]
```

I also added a predict_with_sample size method which will allow you to use this method when you have sufficient data, and switch to a slower algorithm when your data is too sparse.

You may also wish to research k-nearest-neighbours algorithms, particularly if you find too many predictions have a sample size less than is adequate. The algorithm is simple to understand and available in most libraries. (See scikit-learn for python.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm

Finally, you should still perform train-test splits on your data and validate that the model can generalise to new samples.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)

Comment: Regarding logit regression, this will not do what you want as it will take adjacent datapoints information, and many True samples next to a few false will change the prediction of the false.